# How to post both text, image and link at once on friends' walls via facebook API

Tags: ios, facebook

How to let someone post on his/her friends' walls via Facebook API, similar to instagr.am iPhone application lets you post on your own wall?

- How to show a list of friends and allow selecting them?
- How to post both text, image and link at once?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As it happens, Facebook has [an iOS SDK available](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk), and instructions on how to use that to [post feed items](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) (either with an interactive dialog, or with their Graph API).

Comment: Although I'm not sure, I guess feeds dialog will let you post to your own wall _only_.

Answer (score 0):

i did this way. it works fine.. u can post for multiple frnds as well.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params1 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
<appId>, @"api_key",
@"Happy Birthday....", @"message",
@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wFh-rX_Sfhs", @"link",
@"http://www.99desi.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Happy-Birthday.jpg", @"picture",
@"Many More Happy returns Of the Day...", @"name",
@" Believing hear, what you deserve to hear..", @"description",nil];

[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"<frnd-ID>/feed" andParams:params1 andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

u can iterate the above step to post same to multi friends.

hope it helps you...